# How do you inspect a Hibernate list to see if it has been initialized?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-initialization

In Hibernate, let's say you have a class called department and it contains a list of employees.  Is there a way to inspect the list of employees to determine if it has been intialized yet?  It seems no matter what property you access, it gives you the lazy intializer exception.  Is there any way to test it's intialization without getting the exception?

I'd like to see if it has been initializated and if not, just do the query for the data and fill it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to inspect the list of employees to determine if it has
>   been intialized yet?

You could use [Hibernate.isInitialized()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized%28java.lang.Object%29) to check if the hibernate entity is initialized or not.

> I'd like to see if it has been initializated and if not, just do the
>   query for the data and fill it.

You could use [Hibernate.initialize()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29) to force initialization for a hibernate entity . It will query and fill the data for you if it is not initializated yet.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't need to do the query manually -- the entire point of lazy initialization is that the ORM will handle it for you, when it's time to access the data.

If you are getting lazy initialization exception, it means there is no hibernate session open so it can't the fetch children.

Use open-session-in-view (which keeps the session open for the life of the request, in a web app), or initialize the collection up front when the parent is loaded (which has the con of overhead for loading data that might not be needed, which is ok if its always needed).

Comment: I understand the meaning of lazy initialization exception.  The ORM doesn't handle things correctly because it doesn't notify you about it's state.  What it is "supposed" to do is largely irrelevant because it's auto-magic doesn't work.  So I was wondering if it made a way of testing it's state available to you.

Comment: It's just some nerd speak.  I was just annoyed with Hibernate.  Don't worry about it.